How to set a bash variable with environment variables?
I have environment variables
POSTGRES_USER=dbuser
POSTGRES_PASS=dbpasswd
POSTGRES_DBNAME=db
POSTGRES_HOST=123.123.123.123
POSTGRES_PORT=5432

I want to use them in bash script to declare a variable
#!/usr/bin/env bash
DATABASE_URL="postgres://$POSTGRES_USER:$POSTGRES_PASS@$POSTGRES_HOST:$POSTGRES_PORT/$POSTGRES_DBNAME"

How do I properly import my environment variables directly to my bash variable DATABASE_URL?

You don't "import" them in your script, you export them from the calling shell.

You need to clarify the difference between a "variable", an "environment variable", and a "parameter".  It looks like everything you are talking about is just a variable.  If you export the POSTGRES_* in the shell that invokes the script, you can just keep the line you have to assign DATABASE_URL.

I have environment variables "Where" do you "have" them? What does it mean to "have" a variable? If you have a text file containing the text that sets these variables, you can execute that text file as a bash script.

If POSTGRES_USER, etc. were environment variables, then what you have should work. If what you have is not working, I assume that POSTGRES_USER, etc. are not environment variables.  You don't need to (and indeed cannot) "import" them in the script; you need to export them in the caller.  eg:
$ cat assign
POSTGRES_USER=dbuser
POSTGRES_PASS=dbpasswd
POSTGRES_DBNAME=db
POSTGRES_HOST=123.123.123.123
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
$ cat script_without_export 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
. assign
./assign_db_url
$ cat script_with_export 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
. assign
export POSTGRES_USER POSTGRES_PASS POSTGRES_DBNAME POSTGRES_HOST POSTGRES_PORT
./assign_db_url
$ cat assign_db_url 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
DATABASE_URL="postgres://${POSTGRES_USER?}:$POSTGRES_PASS@$POSTGRES_HOST:$POSTGRES_PORT/$POSTGRES_DBNAME"
echo DATABASE_URL=$DATABASE_URL

$ ./script_with_export 
DATABASE_URL=postgres://dbuser:dbpasswd@123.123.123.123:5432/db
$ ./script_without_export 
./assign_db_url: line 2: POSTGRES_USER: parameter null or not set

Note the usage of the defensive ${arg?} here.  A very useful, but oft overlooked construction which aborts the script if arg is not set.  (Compare to ${arg:?} which aborts if arg is unset or if it is the empty string.)
